# Gradient computing

Tags: python, deep-learning, gradient

Assignment 1 from CS231n course.

After loss calculation, I'm asking to implement the gradient of the `scores`
where `scores` is a matrix with N (# of examples) lines and C (classes) columns.

This is the loss calculation:

```
z1 = X.dot(W1) + b1
a1 = np.maximum(0, z1) # pass through ReLU activation function
scores = a1.dot(W2) + b2

# compute the class probabilities
exp_scores = np.exp(scores)
probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True) # [N x K]

# average cross-entropy loss and regularization
corect_logprobs = -np.log(probs[range(N), y])
data_loss = np.sum(corect_logprobs) / N
reg_loss = 0.5 * reg * np.sum(W1 * W1) + 0.5 * reg * np.sum(W2 * W2)
loss = data_loss + reg_loss
```

and this is the gradient calculation: (not mine but it looks similar everywhere)

```
#############################################################################
# TODO: Compute the backward pass, computing the derivatives of the weights #
# and biases. Store the results in the grads dictionary. For example,       #
# grads['W1'] should store the gradient on W1, and be a matrix of same size #
#############################################################################
# compute the gradient on scores
dscores = probs
dscores[range(N),y] -= 1      # The line I don't understand
dscores /= N

# W2 and b2
grads['W2'] = np.dot(a1.T, dscores)
grads['b2'] = np.sum(dscores, axis=0)
# next backprop into hidden layer
dhidden = np.dot(dscores, W2.T)
# backprop the ReLU non-linearity
dhidden[a1 <= 0] = 0
# finally into W,b
grads['W1'] = np.dot(X.T, dhidden)
grads['b1'] = np.sum(dhidden, axis=0)
# add regularization gradient contribution
grads['W2'] += reg * W2
grads['W1'] += reg * W1
```

My question is why I should decrement `dscores`? Why is it a derivative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert.

But what I think that line is basically doing is decrementing the gradient vector only on the correct classes, hence making it more negative so when you once you update the weights it will help the classifier predict the right class.

I may be wrong.